# k2pdfopt: crop and rotate in landscape mode, problem with output device

Tags: pdf

My goal is to move a pdf on my ereader, and I'd like to cut the pdf in two, one upper and one lower part (I would also like to make sure the two parts overlap on around one line to make sure the lines don't get cut in the middle), and then I would like to use it to read on my ereader in landscape mode. So I use this command, for example on [that file](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.02571.pdf):

```
k2pdfopt -mode crop -cbox 0,0,1s,0.51s -cbox 0,0.49s -p 1-2 1707.02571.pdf
```

and I get a result like:

[image]

However, if I use the file "as it", it won't work because my ereader can't rotate the page to read in landscape mode (seems like a bug of the reader). So I'd like to rotate it, but if I use the `-ls` option of `k2pdfopt`with:

```
k2pdfopt -mode crop -cbox 0,0,1s,0.51s -cbox 0,0.49s -p 1-2 -ls 1707.02571.pdf
```

the output is quite different from what I'd expect, as it seems that the text is rotated but not the canvas:

[image]

Any idea what's wrong?

Thanks!

--EDIT--

It seems that the option `-rt 90` works if I change the cropping a bit:

```
k2pdfopt -mode crop -rt 90 -cbox 0,0,0.51s,1s -cbox 0.49s,0 -p 1-2 1707.02571.pdf
```

However, I'm quite curious to know why `-ls` does not work as `-rt` is [not recommended in that setup](https://willus.com/k2pdfopt/help/options.shtml):

> If you're trying to get "landscape" output so that you can turn your
>   reader on its side, use -ls instead of -rt.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is probably a bug in how landscape mode works with crop boxes.  I'll look into it. A way that works is to use the `-grid` option with landscape mode:

```
k2pdfopt -grid 1x2x2 -ls  ...
```

This breaks the page into 1 column x 2 rows with 2% overlap, which is about what you wanted. Even better, I think, is a mode that is specifically designed for this kind of thing, which is the "fit width" mode. This turns the document to landscape and puts as much as it can on each page, looking for a blank row to break the pages and fitting the content width to the edges of the device to minimize wasted margin space.

```
k2pdfopt -mode fw  ...
```

If that is a little too cramped for you, you can force some margins with the `-om` option, e.g.

```
k2pdfopt -mode fw -om .2  ...
```

This is the conversion mode I usually recommend for one-column documents if text re-flow doesn't work well or isn't needed to magnify the text enough.